# Plots and widgets not showing up in bokeh serve

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to build an interactive data visualization tool using bokeh layouts, but I am running into issues when generating and visualizing the plots. When running `bokeh serve --show MWE1.py`, I get the following error message **"Only LayoutDOM items can be inserted into a column. Tried to insert: None of type "** and no plots are generated in my browser window.

When running the code from the command `python MWE1.py` a plot is generated in a browser window, but no slider bar is present. I have also tried to remove the `column` layout tool from `curdoc()` but this didn't seem to help. Is there an issue passing functions that generate plots through curdoc(), and if so, is there an alternative solution?

(As an aside, I have also tried several of the tutorials and examples available online, all of which have worked as intended)

See MWE below:

```
import bokeh
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh import layouts
from bokeh.layouts import column,row,gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show


x=[1, 2, 3]
y=[4, 5, 6]

def p(x,y):
    p = figure()
    p.line(x,y)
    show(p)

q = p(x,y)

freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1, step=0.1)

curdoc().add_root(column(freq,q))'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function `p` is wrong:

1. It doesn't return the plot
2. It calls `show` which doesn't work with `bokeh serve`

Try this instead

```py
def p(x,y):
    p = figure()
    p.line(x,y)
    return p
```